# Tensorflow Apply softmax function only to filters

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let `x` be an tensor of filters of size `(n, w, h, c)`.

I want to apply the `tf.nn.softmax()` function to every filter in that tensor. How can I do that?

I tried the following but got an error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n, c = 2, 2 
h, w = 2, 2

x = tf.ones([n, h, w, c])
y = tf.nn.softmax(x, axis=[1,2])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(x)
    print("x", sess.run(x))
    print("\n")
    print(y)
    print("y", sess.run(y))
```

After the operation, I would expect every filter to be

```
0.25 0.25
0.25 0.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

1. Reshape `x` as follows:

   ```py
   x_r = tf.reshape(x, [n, -1, c])
   ```
2. Apply softmax to filter dimension:

   ```py
   y_r = tf.nn.softmax(x_r, axis=1)
   ```
3. Recover the original shape:

   ```py
   y = tf.reshape(y_r, [n, h, w, c])
   ```